# Парсинг сайта погоды

Tags: android, парсер

Привет.

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать парсер сайта гисметео, который вытаскивает прогноз погоды и записывает его в переменную.

Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: @djbolya, помочь - поможем, только покажите, что вы сделали сами и с чем именно возникли сложности.

Comment: https://www.gismeteo.ru/api/ - чем не устраивает ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С 407 строчки http://www.gismeteo.ru/city/daily/xxxx/ начинаются погодные данные, где хххх - номер вашего города. Когда будете тянуть информацию с помощью программы, номер строки может отличаться. Список номеров городов узнайте на самом сайте. 
Когда Вы определитесь с тем, каким образом и какие именно данные будете тянуть с сайта, можете отписаться сюда, показав часть кода, и вам, скорее всего, помогут. Загоняйте в буфер только нужные строки. Скорее всего, проще будет сначала найти "<h1 class="wtitle">Погода в %название_города%</h1>" в исходном коде страницы, а уж дальше ориентироваться.